# Use of intransitive verbs

Tags: verbs

Would it be grammatically correct to say "a spoon is used to stir" or "a mouse is used to click"

Comment: Yes, however if you don't know this meaning of *mouse*, you may not understand how *click* is being used in your example.

Comment: You can also add a _with_ to indicate instrumental use, but it's not necessary. And why do you think intransitive verbs can't be infinitives?

Comment: It is grammatical, but can you give more context on how you will use it and explain why you don't use an alternative construction. If someone asks  "What is the function of a spoon?" you might reply "A spoon is used to stir."

Answer (score 1):

It is grammatically correct. However, it is not natural to say "a spoon is used to stir" when you are trying to explain what a spoon does.